# Debug embedded javascript file

Tags: asp.net, javascript

There is a class library project with embedded javascript file, with a lot of functions (clint-side implementation), is it possible to debug them?
If I set breakpoints inside this file, they never break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but there is some setup involved - there's an explanation here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx

Once set up it works pretty much the same way you'd debug server-side code.

Edit: I should add that it depends what you're doing as to where is the best place to do your debugging. If you're strictly doing client side debugging then I'd suggest using Firebug etc as suggested by the other answers, if you're moving between client and server side code then it's less clumsy to use the Visual Studio tools as above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug javascript client side with something like Firefox/[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), or IE8 Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging JavaScript has to be done via the client.  Breakpoints in the back end would never be triggered because the back end never actually runs the code.

The method for debugging JavaScript varies by browser.  For Internet Explorer, there is an Internet Developer toolbar and a Script Editor that will help.  For Firefox, tools such as the [FireBug addon](http://getfirebug.com) are very helpful.